# What processing should be done between the calls to create() and show()?

Tags: android, dialog, android-widget

In android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29) it is said that some processing can be done between the call to `create()` and `show()` method of `AlertDialog.Builder` class
what kind of processing should be done?

Answer (score 0):

After create is called, you will get a object to `AlertDialog`. So you can use any of the methods on `AlertDialog`.
`Builder` does not have the finer controls that `AlertDialog` gives. e.g you could use `setCancelMessage(Message msg)` which is not provided in the builder or you could set `setOnShowListener` which is also not provided by builder